# Will my portable app (Portable R) work on both my PC and Mac?

Tags: portable-apps

I installed the portable program onto my usb. I am wondering whether it will work on a MAC computer at school.

EDIT: The program is portable R -> http://portableapps.com/node/32898

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Your question lacks details that are needed to answer it. Where did you download this portable application? [PortableApps](http://portableapps.com/)?

Comment: This is the point of a portable program, they usually do not write their settings in the registry (at least the ones that other programs need to be able to run properly), so after installing/unpacking, You can copy it to any storage device or network share. It will be able to run. More info: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portable_application
EDIT: Of course it will only work on the supported operating system. So if You use a PC at home and download the program with Windows, it will not work on a MAC. They use different file system so it will even be unreadable for the MAC.

Comment: What is your question for Super User now ?

Comment: @The_IT_Guy_You_Don't_Like - I was just writing my next comment where I wanted to explain, that there are ways to be able to do the crosstalk between the two platforms and it is possible to install an .app from Windows that will work on a MAC.

Comment: @Chris - I suggest that You should update your question for something like: "How to install a portable program (define name of the program) from PC (You should name the operating system: ex. Win 7, Win 8, etc.) to run on a MAC from USB drive?"

Comment: I provided the link to the program

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the full documentation about installing R:
http://web.stanford.edu/class/cs109l/unrestricted/handouts/01-InstallingR.pdf

You can download the OSX version from here:
https://cran.r-project.org/bin/macosx/

---

> There can be compatibility issues when attempting to read a PC
>   formatted thumb drive on a Mac, or vice versa. If the thumb drive is
>   working with one operating system, but not the other, it's likely it
>   has been formatted using either NTFS or HFS; causing compatibility
>   between the two architectures. To get both systems to read the drive
>   we suggest formatting it as FAT32 or  MS-DOS using the steps mentioned
>   below.

1. Press the Windows key + E or open Windows Explorer.
2. In the window that appears, locate your thumb drive and right-click it.
3. In the drop-down menu that appears, select Format...
4. In the Format Window, select the format of either FAT or FAT32 and click start.

After You have the .pkg and the formatted usb drive, You just have to copy it and it should be working. If You have any issues, just comment and I will look for solutions.